# Arithmetic progression of rationals

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-progression

We know that the set of rational numbers is countable. For which $n$ can we order all rational numbers as $a_1,a_2,\dots$ so that every subsequence of length $n$ is not an arithmetic progression?

For $n=1,2$ this is trivially impossible. If $n=3$, then the subsequence $a_1,a_2,2a_2-a_1$ forms an arithmetic progression, so it is also impossible. For large enough $n$ it should be possible, though. Is there any reference on this?

Comment: This question was also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970409/arithmetic-progression-of-rationals).

Comment: The existence of such a sequence $(a_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}^+}$ would imply that there exists a permutation of the positive integers which does not contain an $n$-term arithmetic subsequence. This problem is open for $n=4$ according to LeSaulnier--Vijay, and solved for $n=5$ by Davis--Entringer--Graham--Simons.

Comment: The references are as follows. T. D. LeSaulnier, S. Vijay: On Permutations Avoiding Short Progressions, Discrete Mathematics 311(2-3):205-207, [arXiv:1004.1740](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1740). J. A. Davis, R. C. Entringer, R. L. Graham and G. J. Simmons: *On Permutations Containing No Long Arithmetic Progressions*, Acta Arithmetica 34 (1977), 81-90.

Comment: The deleted answer at MSE has a [link](https://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=A669&l=hu) to what appears to be a solution for $n=6$ (unfortunately I don't read Hungarian).

Comment: The authors of the problem, to which Robert Israel linked to, also wrote down their argument in English, see Lemma 8 in G. Károlyi, P. Komjáth: Well Ordering Groups with no Monotone Arithmetic Progressions, Order 34, no. 2 (2017), 299--306, https://doi.org/10.1007/s11083-016-9400-5